# Java programme not locating my FXML file for some reason?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Every time I try to launch this it gives me 'location is required' in the Eclipse console relating to line 17, the one containing the FXMLLoader.

```
public class Main extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
     try {
            StackPane page = new StackPane();
            page = FXMLLoader.load(Main.class.getResource("Sample.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(page);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.setTitle("First JavaFX programme.");
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(Main.class, (java.lang.String[])null);
}
```

}

Comment: Try name it something else? I remember that I got same problem when I named my file View. When I changed it to MainView it worked.

Comment: Is `Sample.fxml` in the same package as the `Main` class?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to make sure that *Sample.fxml* is in a resources directory. I think the answer to your question already exists [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28266492/location-is-required-exception-when-loading-fxml-file)

Comment: I think he's using Eclipse as IDE.