# Why can't I launch this simple FXML hello world application?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, fxml

I am currently in the process of migrating my hastily-made JavaFX application layout from Java to FXML so I can worry about the style, view, controller, and model all seperately, but I can't seem to able to run a simple hello world application.

I get the following error:

```
 Exception in Application start method
 java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

Here is the View.fxml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<VBox prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="calend.ae.Controller">

    <Label text="I love bacon"/>
    <Button text="Submit"/>

</VBox>
```

and the main class

```
package calend.ae;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Model extends Application {

    public static void main(String[]args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stg) throws Exception{
        Parent tabs = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("View.fxml"));
        stg.setTitle("Hello World");
        stg.setScene(new Scene(tabs, 450, 250));
        stg.show();
    }
}
```

You can find the entirety of the source code [here](https://github.com/Zunon/Calendae/tree/FXML-testing). I only want to know why it doesn't run, for context here is the actual [application](https://github.com/Zunon/Calendae/tree/master)

Here is the full stack trace:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
    at calend.ae.Model.start(Model.java:17)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application calend.ae.Model
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
```

Comment: Post your code here not in an external site

Comment: Also post the full stack trace.

Comment: @James_D posted, thanks.

Comment: @Reimus posted, thanks.

Comment: There are several questions on SO with this error: have you looked at any of them? E.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28266492/location-is-required-exception-when-loading-fxml-file

Comment: @James_D yes, I tried several solutions similar to this, none of them seemed to have any effect.

Comment: Looks like your FXML file is not being deployed along with the class files when the jar file is built. How are you creating the jar file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using maven or ant?

If you use ant the fxml should go in the same dir where Model.java is

Comment: I don't know which, I am using eclipse on (mostly) default settings, but I tried both in the root directory and beside Model.java, no effect.

Comment: if it's maven you probably have 2 folders in your src dir. "java" and "resources" Create a fxml folder inside resources and place the fxml file there.

Comment: Ah, it works now, the github desktop program put the fxml file back beside the model.java, I guess it removed it from there before sync. thanks